# The "preying" mantis female is said to devour its "mail" during copulation. Considering these mistakes unintentional, what would we call them?

Tags: orthography, puns

Is there such thing as "a written malapropism" or "a slip of the pen"?  Or are they just simple spelling mistakes? If they were unintentional, they couldn't be considered puns or a play with words, I presume.

Comment: And they say that [philately](https://www.google.com/search?q=philately) [will get you nowhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=flattery+will+get+you+nowhere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one you've listed (presuming the qoutes are yours) is a simple [homophones](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/homophone):

> (Linguistics) one of a group of words pronounced in the same way but differing in meaning or spelling or both, as for example bear and bare.

It's not a pun, because eating its *mail* makes no sense.

A [slip of the pen](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/Slip-Of-The-Pen.htm) is regarded as a type of heterophemy, the unintentional use of an incorrect or inappropriate word or phrase in speech or writing. - Richard Nordquist

Comment: If you really think "devouring ones mail during copulation" nonsensical you are fortunate. I now can't get out of my head "Just put the tablet down for a moment, all right?".

Comment: @TimLymington - people read their emails? Seriously?

Comment: or social media ... *Honey, my status just got 5 likes.*

Answer (score 0):

If the sentence includes the double-quotes *(as in your post title),*  you can presume that the usage is deliberate.  Without the double-quotes, the error is using the wrong heterograph.

See:

[error type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym)